# angularjs Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, cors, mean

[source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWzKQ.png) when I POST data from postman it shows an correct response data,
but when i POST data using app(client) side it shows an Failed to load http://localhost:3000/done: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404

Answer (score -1):

At the time of data posting, your local server (means backend server should be on), and post the data through, Header,queryparam or body,

and make sure that same params, you are recieving at backend side,

```
 $http.post('http://localhost:9191/api/signin', {
    username: 'some username',
    password: 'some password'
  }, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'key': '123'
    }
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response)
  });
```

And **don't use json.stringify for data object, now send only object.**

Comment: all set in correct way.bt it shows an preflight response

Comment: can you share the code with us??

Comment: yes,i added that

Comment: make sure that, you write the "application/json"

Comment: check that, i have added the code for you.